# CNN to detect presence/absense of label on images with mixed labels

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, classification, multi-label-classification, image-recognition

Here's my problem: I work with medical image classification, and currently I have 3 classes:

- class A: images with lesion 1 only; and images with lesion 1 and N other lesions
- class B: images with 2 other lesions (no lesion 1)
- class C: images with no lesion

The goal is to classify into "lesion 1", "other lesion", "no lesion". I'd like to know some approach/method/paper/clue for this classification. I think the presence of other lesions on both class A and B is confusing the model (the validation accuracy and f1-score are very low).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say "I think the presence of other lesions on both class A and B is confusing the model". Can you please explain a little bit about how you are training your model? What model are you using? What is your loss function? How many training and validation data do you have?

Comment: Hi. I'm using resnet50, and used categorical cross entropy and kullback leibler divergence losses. Both with similar results. I have 2000 images for class A (1300 wth mixed lesions), 1500 for class B, and 800 for class C. I'm applying 10-fold cross validation.